# The following packages have unmet dependencies: containerd.io

Tags: apt, docker, dpkg

I am trying to install the following packages on my brand new ubuntu 22.04 installation.

`sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose -y`

However I get an error about

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 containerd.io : Conflicts: containerd
                 Conflicts: runc
```

The full error is below

```
~/temporary_files$ sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 containerd.io : Conflicts: containerd
                 Conflicts: runc
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Could you help me solve this?

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a solution. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove containerd.io
sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose -y
systemctl start docker
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

Now everything works

Comment: This also worked for me on Ubuntu 22.4

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 too. thanks.